# Can't get yuidoc running on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: node.js, yui

On installing yuidoc I'm getting the following warning.

```
npm WARN package.json connect@1.9.2 No README.md file found!
```

When trying to start yuidoc --server later it shows me:

```
info: (yuidoc): Scanning for yuidoc.json file.
error: (yuidoc): Scanned 5001 directories looking for a yuidoc.json file, something is probably wrong here..
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What directory are you running yuidoc from? The warning is from connect, that's normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is nothing to worry about.

The error is that you haven't provided a yuidoc.json file:

http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/args/index.html#json